# C# how do I read an mdb(MS Access) file then pass in the retrieved columns selected in an array for later use?

Tags: c#

How do I read an mdb file then pass in the retrieved columns selected in an array? Basically, I am trying to retrieve items that match 2 specified criteria columns that then save the last column in an array.

I have the printed results correct as per the two criterias them being qDC and qPL but now when printing them how do I save the last row for later use in an array.

```
var list = new List<MyData>();
   while (true)
   {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
          var data = new MyData
           {
              ColumnOne = reader.GetString(0),
              ColumnTwo = reader.GetString(1),
              ColumnThree = reader.GetString(2),
              ColumnFour = reader.GetString(3),
              ColumnFive = reader.GetString(4),
            };
           list.Add(data);

           Console.WriteLine("");
           foreach (var row in list)
           {
             Console.WriteLine("Start Here");
             Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnOne); 
             Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnTwo); 
             Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnThree); 
             Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnFour); 
             Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnFive);//Email
             Console.WriteLine(""); 
           }
```

I am trying to use these emails (in column 5) as a mass bcc email chain

Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save the columns to variables in your `while (reader.Read())` loop. when reader.Read() returns false, you will have the last row values stored in the variables. Then you can do whatever you wish with them.

Update:
you can store values from each row in a [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) object.

Update 2:

```
// you need a class to hold all of the columns in a row
class MyData {
  public string ColumnOne { get; set; }
  public string ColumnTwo { get; set; }
  public string ColumnThree { get; set; }
  public string ColumnFour { get; set; }
}


// list to hold instances of the class created above
var list = new List<MyData>();
/* code to connect and open reader */
while(reader.Read()) {
  // store your row
  var data = new MyData {
    ColumnOne = reader.GetString(0),
    ColumnTwo = reader.GetString(1),
    ColumnThree = reader.GetString(2),
    ColumnFour = reader.GetString(3),
  };
  // add it to the list
  list.Add(data);
}
// you can loop through the list using a foreach loop
foreach(var row in list) {
  Console.WriteLine("Start Here");
  Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnOne);
  Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnTwo);
  Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnThree);
  Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnFour);
  Console.WriteLine(); // you don't need to pass in an empty string
}
```

Comment: When I do this it returns one value and not all the values in the actual column. Hence, the variable is being overwritten each time it loops. Is there a way to add to an array rather than just call that single variable?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can use the List<T> object to store each row. It does not require a predefined size upon declaration like an array does.

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to understand the use of List before but I am confused on how I can use it here or how to implement it?

Comment: updated my answer again with an example of how to use the List class

Comment: For some reason when I enter this code 'var list = new List<MyData>', it throws this error: Thanks by the way :    

Error 1 - A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type

Comment: you need parenthesis when calling a constructor.

Comment: Yea that did it haha sorry it's so weird coding in C# thanks so much. wish i could give u rep but im new so i cant give any. Cheers.

Comment: Never mind that I figure out that my loop needs to exclude some code.
Thanks!